# Подгрузка php скрипта без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, html, javascript

Имеется главная страница: *index.html*, [**примерная структура**](http://imageshack.com/a/img89/3480/nj9t.png).
Необходимо подгрузить php скрипт на этой же странице, без перезагрузки при этом взял данные из формы. Можете привести пример кода?

Comment: @XenK, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
функция обработки ответа аякс запроса
    function(data){
      $('#content').html($('#content').html+data);
    }

второй вариант так же можно использовать 
    function(data){
      $('#content').append(data);
    }
```